# Join Multiple tables in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
            var z = from x in resp1.table1
                    join y in resp2.table2 on x.fields equals y.fields
                    select
                    new {y.fields, y.fields1, x.fields2, x.fields3, x.fields4};
```

And I want a new table so basically I want to join three or more tables but I dont know how

Comment: Are you having a problem with that linq query?

Comment: the Table 1 have the primary key of table2 and table3, and I want to have all the fields of table2 and table3. How should I do it?

Comment: No. but I dont know how to query three tables. As you can see in my code above it only have two tables. And I want to have to join three tables which is the table1 have the primary key of table2 and table3.

Answer (score 1):

```
var z = from x in resp1.table1
        join y in resp2.table2 on x.fields equals y.fields
        join z in resp3.table3 on x.fields equals z.fields
        select
        new {y.fields, y.fields1, x.fields2, x.fields3, x.fields4, z.fields5, z.fields6};
```

And so on... But first check if you [really need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355502/help-with-a-three-table-linq-query) a triple join!

Comment: Lastly how can I short it ascending using the table1 fields?

Comment: @Therence before the select line use `orderby fieldName1, fieldName2` replacing the fieldNames with the proper ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
var z = from x in resp1.table1
        join y in resp2.table2 on x.fields equals y.fields
        join z in resp3.table3 on x.fields equals z.fields
        select
        new {y.fields, y.fields1, x.fields2, x.fields3, x.fields4, z.fields5};
```

Comment: Lastly how can I short it ascending using the table1 fields?